# Open docker to internet from azure Redhat server without IP forwarding

Tags: azure, docker, routes, port

I have 5 docker containers running inside Azure Redhat Server. If IP forwarding is enabled it works over the internet.
As a security issue need to disable IP forwarding.
Is there any solution like switching it from docker0 to eth0?